# Does PyCharm remote debugging support Windows server?

Tags: pycharm

Does PyCharm remote debugging support Windows server?

When I connect to Windows Server 2012 R2, it said the sudo or env is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
If support, could you mind tell me how to solve it in detail, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It does not at the moment, unfortunately. The relevant ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20952